# Не работают php файлы

Tags: javascript, php, openserver

Я запустил локальный сервер через openserver и в папку domains добавил свою папку с файлами, когда пользователь входит в аккаунт я в js отслеживаю нажатие на кнопку и через window.location перенаправляю пользователя на другой php файл, но вместо того чтобы он норм открылся там выдает это, что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так попробуйте перейти на файл сами без js. Если работает -  наверное адрес неправильный при window.location

Comment: не epilog, а epilog.php в вашем случае